# Show $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is there any simple proof that these two are not homeomorphic?

Comment: I guess that depends on your notion of simple :)

Comment: What would be "allowed" to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know if this proof is simple.

No they are not.

For $n>2$

The space $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ is NOT $\textbf{contractible}$ but $\Bbb{R}^n$ is

Contractibility is a topological invariant.

For $n=1$ again they are not since $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is not connected.

Comment: is there  a proof that does not use any of the concepts introduced with homotopy?

Comment: @aldodecristo You can do it with homology, but that also involves the concept of homotopy.

Comment: Doesn't *simply connected* indicate a space with trivial $\pi_1$ (which $\Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ have for all $n>2$)?

Comment: This answer is not correct. $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is simply connected for all $n\geq 3.$ What is true is that $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ has nontrivial higher homotopy groups but this is not an easy theorem to prove.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip..i changed my answer to contractible..this is what i meant with simple connectedness,but they are different notion..a contractible space is simply connected though

Comment: Still it is not proved that $\mathbb R^n \backslash \{ 0 \}$ is not contractible.

Answer (score 3):

For $n=1$, you can use the simple argument that $\mathbb{R}$ is connected while $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is not connected.

For $n = 2$, you need to be smarter. Here is an answer using fundamental groups.
We have:
$$\pi_1(\mathbb{R}^2) \cong \{0\}$$
since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex (and we can consider linear homotopies). On the other hand,

$$\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}\cong S^{1}\times ]0, \infty[$$

via the homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}\to S^{1}\times ]0, \infty[: x \mapsto (x/\Vert x \Vert, \Vert x\Vert)$.

So $$\pi_1( \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}) \cong \pi_1(S^{1} \times ]0, \infty[) \cong \pi_1(S^{1}) \times \pi_1(]0,\infty [) \cong \mathbb{Z}$$

and the fundamental groups are different.

For higher dimensions, you can use the same arguments but with higher homology groups instead.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to show that $\mathbb R^n$ is contractible. In fact, the map:

$$H: \mathbb R^n\times [0, 1]\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$$ given by $$H(x, t):=(1-t)x$$ gives us a homotopy between the identity map of $\mathbb R^n$ and the constant map $c(x):=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R^n$.

It is also easy to see that if $X$ is homeomorphic to a contractible space $Y$ then $X$ is itself contractible. In fact, let $$f: X\longrightarrow Y$$ be an homeomorphim and let $$H: Y\times [0, 1]\longrightarrow Y$$ be an homotopy between the identity map $\textrm{id}_Y$ of $Y$ and a constant map $c: Y\longrightarrow Y$. Define $$\overline{H}: X\times [0, 1]\longrightarrow X$$ setting $$\overline{H}(x, t):= f^{-1}(H(f(x), t)).$$ Then $\overline{H}$ is continuous and $$\overline{H}(x, 0)=f^{-1}(H(f(x), 0))=f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$ and $$\overline{H}(x, 1)=f^{-1}(H(f(x), 1))=f^{-1}(c(f(x)),$$ which is constant for every $x$. Therefore $\overline{H}$ is a homotopy between the identity map $\textrm{id}_X$ of $X$ and the constant map $$c_f(x):=f^{-1}(c(f(x)),$$ for every $x\in X$. Thus $X$ is also contractible.

Pluggin this into your problem, if $\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$ were homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ then $\mathbb R^n-\{0\}$ would be contractible, which is not the case.

Comment: But how do you show that $\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ is not contractible? Usually one uses some algebraic topology for this.

Comment: I believe you can prove this by contradiction using homotopies..

Comment: it is not that simple to show.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid any use of homotopy or homology, there's this (for $n \geq 2$): Remove any compact subset from $\mathbb R^n$ and the remainder has only one component whose closure in the whole space is not compact. With $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ you can get two.  Or (equivalently): $\Bbb{R}^n \setminus \{0\}$ has a two-point compactification but $\mathbb R^n$ does not.